# can't convert array to image correctly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, opencv

I want to read an image from file resize it to square dimension(resize) and then convert array to image for show it. So i write the code below for it, but unfortunately fromarray method does not show true image at last..how can I fix it? (i don't want use opencv or another builtin function)

```
#import the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import toimage

#reading the image
myimage = cv2.imread('mahdi.png')

#plotting the image
cv2.imshow('mahdi',myimage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#save
cv2.imwrite('newmahdi.png',myimage)

#get size of image
dimensions = myimage.shape
height = myimage.shape[0]
width = myimage.shape[1]
print('Image Dimension    : ',dimensions)
print('Image Height       : ',height)
print('Image Width        : ',width,'\n')

#read image and convert to array
myimage1=mpimg.imread('mahdi.png')
imtopix = np.array(myimage1)
print('image to matrix:','\n',imtopix)

#resize image without OPENCV function... use numpy instead
myimage2 =np.resize(imtopix,(200,200))
newimg = Image.fromarray(myimage2)
newimg.save('my.png')
newimg.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's `resize()` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't resample an array along its axes.

Say your source array looks like this:

```
array([
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
      ])
```

Then after an `a = np.resize(a, (3, 3))` the result will look like this:

```
array([
        [11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 21],
        [22, 23, 24]
      ])
```

As you can see, the original first row runs over into the second row and so on while the last pixel simply vanished. This happens because `np.resize()` doesn't actually change any data. It just assigns a different shape to the data that exists in memory while the original rows stay in consecutive order to each other (or columns, if you used a Fortran-style array).

What you actually want is Pillow's [`resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize):

```
newimg = Image.fromarray(imtopix)
newimg = newimg.resize((200, 200), resample=Image.BILINEAR)
```

Choose whatever resampling method is appropriate for your use case.